# Trim Characters before and after from sql table column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

From below sentence

```
"Out of Stock  - N1452002 @ £22.56"
```

I want to *extract*

```
N1452002
```

and show in a separate column, Can any one please help me with this. Your advise is highly apprecaited.

Comment: What rdbms are you using? String manipulation is usually done with vendor-specific code.

Comment: I am using microsoft sql server

Comment: Logically you need to get value between '-' and '@' , or something else do you need ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the string always has the same format and that the code is always 8 characters, you just need a substring function:

```
select substring(str, 17, 8)
```

That is my simplest interpretation of what you want.

If you want to find the first "code" in the string -- and it follows the format you specified, then this should work:

```
select left(stuff(str, 1, patindex('% [A-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', str
                 ), ''), 8
           )
```

Answer (score 0):

with SQL Server 2016 there was `string_split` introduced:

```
select value from string_split('Out of Stock  - N1452002 @ £22.56', ' ') where left(value, 1) = 'N'
```

Comment: I got sql server 2014 so this function wouldnt work I am afraide thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0):

You can play with `SUBSTRING` and `CHARINDEX` like below, it will work if always before your required string is - and space, and after your required string space and @

```
declare @string nvarchar(50) = 'Out of Stock  - N1452002 @ £22.56'
select substring(@string, CHARINDEX('-', @string) + 2, 
                    CHARINDEX('@', @string)-3 - CHARINDEX('-', @string))
```

Comment: amended your code slighlty like this "select substring(Description, CHARINDEX('-', Description) + 2, 
                    CHARINDEX('@', Description)-3 - CHARINDEX('-', Description))

FROM            Accounts_Codes_"  But getting an error "Msg 537, Level 16, State 3, Line 2
Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function."

Comment: @Randy, it is because for some rows CHARINDEX('@', @Description)-3 - CHARINDEX('-', @Description) is negative

Comment: you are right " CHARINDEX('-', @Description) is negative" thanks for the reply

Answer (score 0):

in order to mitigate against the risk of the left most text containing @ or - characters, I came up with this.  As long as you don't have '-' or @ to the right of where they are now, 
as long as the cash amount cannot have a - sign on it.

```
DECLARE @TEST AS nvarchar(200) = 'Out of Stock test @chars extra - etc  - N1452002 @ £22.56';


SELECT REVERSE(
            RTRIM(
                LEFT(
                        RIGHT(REVERSE(@TEST),LEN(@TEST) - CHARINDEX('@',REVERSE(@TEST))
                    ) , charindex('-', RIGHT(REVERSE(@TEST),LEN(@TEST) - CHARINDEX('@',REVERSE(@TEST))))-1)
                  )
                )
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply getting the following error "Msg 537, Level 16, State 3, Line 16
Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function."

Comment: I presume that's not with your sample string, which works ok for me, and is all I had to go on.  But since you've found an answer anyway, good luck with your project!